# InvalidOperationException when registering a new user with ASP .NET Core Identity and EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-identity

I'm following the [documentation for using Identity](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/identity.html) and am trying register a new user (executing the register action), but it fails with the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'ApplicationUser'
>   because this type is not included in the model for the context.

Startup:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    //password options
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    // ...
})
```

I am using a standard ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

Register action in AccountController:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = viewModel.UserName, Email = viewModel.Email };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, viewModel.Password); //<-- Exception happens here
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            _logger.LogInformation(3, "User created a new account with password.");
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
        }

        string errorData = "";
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            errorData += error.Description + '\n';
        }
        StoreErrorMessage("Failed to create the user!", errorData);
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

I already tried the following:

- Adding `DbSet<ApplicationUser>` to `AplicationContext`
- I did create and apply a new migration via `dotnet ef`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the problem. My `ApplicationContext` was inheriting from `DbContext`. I changed it to `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` and it works.

Comment: Is this solution work for reverse engineering i.e. for database first approach?

Comment: I'm still having the same problem while applying this fix

Comment: I suppose you're using the IdentityDbContext from the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore namespace?

Comment: This is the solution to the problem. Remenber to change in the startup this ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 2):

Create new context class which inherit IdentityDbContext.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

and in startup.cs file add below code

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

This will help you for database first approach.

Comment: I can't believe I have to have 2 DbContexts but okay it works.

Comment: you don't need two DbContexts. Just inherit your DbContext from IdentityDbContext (which inherits DbContext)